# Servicio WCF recibe 0 en parametros int o decimal

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Tengo un metodo en el WCF que recibe dos parametros (int Id, Item item)

Item esta compuesto de la siguiente manera:

```
/// <summary>
/// Pasaje de datos a pagar
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Barcode;
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Importe;
    [DataMember]
    public string Token;
    [DataMember]
    public string ConceptoCode;
    [DataMember]
    public string ConceptoDescription;
    [DataMember]
    public int CajeroId;
    [DataMember]
    public string TipoComprobante;
    [DataMember]
    public string NumeroComprobante;
    [DataMember]
    public string MetodoConsulta;
}
```

Mi problema es que al llamar al metodo desde mi app relleno el objeto pero cuando llega al metodo del servicio el CajeroId y Importe llegan con valor 0.

Intente actualizar la referencia al servicio, eliminarla y crearla de nuevo y de todas maneras llega 0 pero si yo le pego al servicio de forma externa con SOAPUI los valores llegan de manera correcta.

Referencia de versiones anteriores

```
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="KioskServiceReference.IKioskService")]

public interface IKioskService {
             [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/CancelOperation", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/CancelOperationResponse")]
            GcbaKiosk.KioskServiceReference.CancelOperationStatus CancelOperation(int kioskId, string barcode, decimal importe, string token, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, int> bills, int cajeroId, string TipoComprobante, string NumeroComprobante);

            [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/CancelOperation", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/CancelOperationResponse")]
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GcbaKiosk.KioskServiceReference.CancelOperationStatus> CancelOperationAsync(int kioskId, string barcode, decimal importe, string token, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, int> bills, int cajeroId, string TipoComprobante, string NumeroComprobante);

            [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/NullifyOperation", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/NullifyOperationResponse")]
            GcbaKiosk.KioskServiceReference.CancelOperationStatus NullifyOperation(int kioskId, string barcode, decimal importe, string token, int OT, int cajeroId, string TipoComprobante, string NumeroComprobante);

            [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/NullifyOperation", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/NullifyOperationResponse")]
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GcbaKiosk.KioskServiceReference.CancelOperationStatus> NullifyOperationAsync(int kioskId, string barcode, decimal importe, string token, int OT, int cajeroId, string TipoComprobante, string NumeroComprobante);
```

Referencia de version actual

```
   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="KioskServiceReference.IKioskService")]
    public interface IKioskService {

        // CODEGEN: El parámetro 'CancelOperationResult' requiere información adicional de esquema que no se puede capturar con el modo de parámetros. El atributo específico es 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute'.
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/CancelOperation", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/CancelOperationResponse")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(BaseOperation))]
        GcbaKiosk.KioskServiceReference.CancelOperationResponse CancelOperation(GcbaKiosk.KioskServiceReference.CancelOperationRequest request);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/CancelOperation", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/CancelOperationResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GcbaKiosk.KioskServiceReference.CancelOperationResponse> CancelOperationAsync(GcbaKiosk.KioskServiceReference.CancelOperationRequest request);

        // CODEGEN: El parámetro 'NullifyOperationResult' requiere información adicional de esquema que no se puede capturar con el modo de parámetros. El atributo específico es 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute'.
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/NullifyOperation", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/NullifyOperationResponse")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(BaseOperation))]
        GcbaKiosk.KioskServiceReference.NullifyOperationResponse NullifyOperation(GcbaKiosk.KioskServiceReference.NullifyOperationRequest request);

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/NullifyOperation", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IKioskService/NullifyOperationResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GcbaKiosk.KioskServiceReference.NullifyOperationResponse> NullifyOperationAsync(GcbaKiosk.KioskServiceReference.NullifyOperationRequest request);
```

Saludos.

Solucion:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150859/service-reference-generates-incorrect-method-signature

Por alguna razon no estaba tomando bien las referencias pero al eliminar el servicio y generarlo de nuevo pero seleccionando los ensamblados de forma manual la referencia volvio a generarse correctamente.

Espero que les sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: validaste que la clase Item que usas desde el cliente sea la que crea el Service Reference ? y no sea otra clase Item que definas en el codigo del cliente

Comment: Si la valide y es la que corresponde, lo raro es que tanto el metodo como la llamada no sufrieron cambios a nivel codigo yo supongo que al actualizar la referencia para otras cosas  afecto la referencia y es lo que genera el problema voy a intentar ir aplicando los nuevos cambios sobre una version de la app donde esto funcionaba correctamente no se me ocurre otra solucion.

Comment: Intente poner todo el codigo en una version anterior y tampoco funciono. La referencia al servicio genera cambios raros. Siempre actualize la referencia y nunca me genero semejante cambio y agregado de lineas para todos los metodos.

Comment: por las dudas, intentaste suar propiedades `public string Barcode {get;set;}`